# VB.Net Substring Error

Tags: vb.net, substring

At the moment, I have three different times that the following code is ran, back-to-back just with the variables changed:

```
    txtCourseName.LoadFile(strRootLocation + "\subject\" + strSubject + "\" + "\class\" + cmbCourses.SelectedItem, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)
    aData = txtCourseName.Text
    i = aData.IndexOf("<h3 class=""panel-title"">") + "<h3 class=""panel-title"">".Length
    j = aData.IndexOf("</h3>") - i
    txtCourseName.Text = aData.Substring(i, j)
```

For every time it is ran, the rich-text box that is being used is changed, aData is changed to bData, cData, etc., and the data that `i` and `j` are indexing is changed. It will run properly for the first two iterations, returning what it is supposed to into the text box, however on the third one, it gives me a `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException` with the additional information of `Length cannot be less than zero`.

My only assumption for what could be causing this is that the third iteration, which I included below, is only supposed to find a 7-letter long string of characters and this is causing some math issues.

I have no idea how to fix this.

```
    txtCourseNumber.LoadFile(strRootLocation + "\subject\" + strSubject + "\" + "\class\" + cmbCourses.SelectedItem, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)
    cData = txtCourseNumber.Text
    i = cData.IndexOf("Course Number: </b>") + "Course Number: </b>".Length
    j = cData.IndexOf("</li>") - i
    txtCourseNumber.Text = cData.Substring(i, j)
```

### Example Data That Is Returned By Each Iteration

aData - "English 4"
bData - "insert some really long course description here"
cData - "10045C"

Comment: That seems to be HTML, don't "parse" html with string methods, not even with regex. Use [`HtmlAgilityPack`](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Comment: I did it that way because the HTML page had already been created, therefore the code was just finding a certain string, and looking at the data between that string and the second string. I will look into your suggestion though.

Comment: When you debug in VS what are the values of `i` and `j` on the third iteration?

Comment: `i` = 1565 & `j` = -64.

Comment: I have managed to figure out what was happening and fix it. Thanks for your help!  
  
It was checking for the first </li> instead of the one that was after the initial string I gave it. Within the HTML file, I added a class to the closing tag (I know, I know, not the best thing to do) and then it solved my issues. (No, probably not the best way to do it but it works.)